# Exception Handler in Spring boot not working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am implementing global error handling in my project using Spring boot. I am throwing a "ResourceNotFoundException" when my "Customer" object is "null". But the Spring exception handler is not catching it.

**My RestController class:**

```
@RestController
@Path("/customer")
public class CustomerEndpoint {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerEndpoint.class);

    @Autowired
    private ICustomerService customerService;


    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getCustomerById(@PathParam("id") Integer id) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    CustomerVO article = customerService.getCustomerById(id);
    if (article == null) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(customerId, "Customer not found");
        }
        return Response.ok(article).build();
    }
}
```

**My ExceptionHandler:**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandlerController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> resourceNotFound(ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
        ExceptionResponse response = new ExceptionResponse();
        response.setErrorCode("resource not found");
        response.setErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
   }
```

**ExceptionResponse:**

```
    public class ExceptionResponse {

    private String errorCode;
    private String errorMessage;

    public ExceptionResponse() {
    }

    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

**ResourceNotFoundException class:**

```
    public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException{

    private long resourceId;
    private String message;

    public ResourceNotFoundException(long resourceId, String message) {
        super(message);
        this.resourceId = resourceId;
        this.message = message;
    }
    public ResourceNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Please observe the RestController class. When I get a request for a customer with an id , if the customer is not present it throws ResourceNotFound exception. By default this needs to be catched by the ExceptionHandler. But instead of this I am getting the stackTrace like following. Please help me in catching this exception globally.

```
com.finsol.qunatotrade.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Customer not found
    at com.finsol.qunatotrade.service.CustomerService.getCustomerById(CustomerService.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.finsol.qunatotrade.service.CustomerService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5c04d986.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.finsol.qunatotrade.service.CustomerService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ddc81d1f.getCustomerById(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.finsol.qunatotrade.api.endpoint.CustomerEndpoint.getCustomerById(CustomerEndpoint.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at com.finsol.qunatotrade.api.filter.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]

2018-01-29 17:37:20.264 DEBUG 2304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-01-29 17:37:20.265  INFO 2304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-01-29 17:37:20.266  INFO 2304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-01-29 17:37:20.266 DEBUG 2304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Using MultipartResolver [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver@13ba49b5]
2018-01-29 17:37:20.274 DEBUG 2304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate LocaleResolver with name 'localeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver@18ee3eeb]
2018-01-29 17:37:20.280 DEBUG 2304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate ThemeResolver with name 'themeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver@583d7e84]
2018-01-29 17:37:20.289 DEBUG 2304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate RequestToViewNameTranslator with name 'viewNameTranslator': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@6611f464]
2018-01-29 17:37:20.303 DEBUG 2304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate FlashMapManager with name 'flashMapManager': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@29de5bb4]
2018-01-29 17:37:20.303 DEBUG 2304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'dispatcherServlet' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcherServlet]
2018-01-29 17:37:20.303  INFO 2304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 37 ms
2018-01-29 17:37:20.303 DEBUG 2304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Servlet 'dispatcherServlet' configured successfully
2018-01-29 17:37:20.305 DEBUG 2304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2018-01-29 17:37:20.310 DEBUG 2304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2018-01-29 17:37:20.330 DEBUG 2304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2018-01-29 17:37:20.331 DEBUG 2304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
2018-01-29 17:37:20.451 DEBUG 2304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Written [{timestamp=Mon Jan 29 17:37:20 IST 2018, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, exception=com.finsol.qunatotrade.exception.ResourceNotFoundException, message=Customer not found, path=/qtregistration/customer/1}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@6344227]
2018-01-29 17:37:20.452 DEBUG 2304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2018-01-29 17:37:20.452 DEBUG 2304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request



enter code here
```

Comment: try like this https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned, `@ControllerAdvice` cannot be used for Jersey. You can use `ExceptionMapper` with the annotation `@Provider` that maps Java exceptions to Jersey response.

**The ExceptionHandler:**

```
@Provider
public class GlobalExceptionHandlerController implements ExceptionMapper<ResourceNotFoundException> {
  @Override
  public Response toResponse(ResourceNotFoundException e) {
    ExceptionResponse response = new ExceptionResponse();
    response.setErrorCode("resource not found");
    response.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());

    return Response.status(404).entity(response)
    .type("application/json").build();
  }
}
```

Don't forget to register this GlobalExceptionHandlerController just like your CustomerEndpoint:

```
@Configuration
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
  public JerseyConfig() {
    register(GlobalExceptionHandlerController.class);
    register(CustomerEndpoint.class); // your existing controller
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it made my day. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that GlobalExceptionHandlerController is NOT visible to spring. See how are doing it for service classes. If GlobalExceptionHandlerController is under a package which is getting scanned alright, then you could try this code instead:

```
@Provider
public class ErrorResponseHandler implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable>{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ErrorResponseHandler.class);

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable error) {
        if (error instanceof ResourceNotFoundException) {
            ....
            ....              
        } 
        else if (error instanceof JsonProcessingException) {
            logger.error("Could not interpret incoming request", error);
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(error.getMessage()).build();
        } 
        else{
            return response;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I am getting the errors : "type ExceptionMapper doesn't take parameters" and also "the implemented method is not overriding the super type".

Answer (score 0):

use @RestControllerAdvice as your response is in ResponseEntity

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandlerController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> resourceNotFound(ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
    ExceptionResponse response = new ExceptionResponse();
    response.setErrorCode("resource not found");
    response.setErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
   }
```